# Instagram API cannot update user information

Tags: api, instagram

So far as I know, we can use Twitter API to update user information such as name, location, etc.

Can I use Instagram API to update Instagram user information just like Twitter API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram's API does not allow you to update User information. You can modify relationships between users (follow, unfollow, block, etc), but that is it.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: thanks. why dont they allow? it does not hurt any user, just like twitter